# How to show icon of gps on Action Bar?

Tags: android

In the Maps app, if GPS is enabled , On Action Bar has got an icon for GPS.
Now, if my app want to show an icon for gps on Action Bar ( the same as Maps App).
How must I do?

Comment: You want only to show this icon? Or you want to use GPS and the icon to be shown when you use it?

Comment: The gps icon in the action bar is automatically shown when the current app is using the gps. If your app uses the GPS it will be shown. Is your question about showing the icon without using the GPS?

Comment: My app uses the GPS , but don't show icon on Action Bar the same  Map App has got icon circle on Action Bar(if gps disable, icon circle will hide).

Comment: Then there are two posibilities. First - your usage of GPS isn't working properly. Second - your phone has GPS turned off.

Comment: GPS turn on, Map App has show icon  circle if i turn on GPS and hide icon if i turn off GPS.

Comment: Then what about your app and GPS usage inthere?

Comment: I think, if you are switchOFF your GPS, your A_GPS is enabled, so you have coordinates of location!!! But don't have icon at the top!!!) If GPS is disabled - NO icon! Enabled - YES icon)

Comment: @– timonvlad yes, the same icon of wifi.